# ipfs-infrua, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () ipfs-infura

Tags: ipfs, image-formats, next-images, infura

The image is not displayed, infura ipfs, I got this error,
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
GET https://dmarket.vercel.app/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdmarket1.infura-ipfs.io%2Fipfs%2FQmWCEvkdJCarGE8kdGVWxoYf2RWzZN1KDtFSSehSiR4uxx&w=1080&q=75 400

i try to edit next.config.js but not work
it may be cause from infura-ipfs
images: {
domains: ["assets.vercel.com", "infura-ipfs.io", "ipfs.infura.io", "dmarket.infura-ipfs.io"],
//domains: ["assets.vercel.com", "dmarket.infura-ipfs.io", ""],
formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"],
unoptimized: true,
fill: true
},